# Python 2.7 String decode failed.

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I expect the following code works fine, but it's failing, what is the reason?

```
>>> s = 'ö'
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Your string is not encoded in utf-8. What console are you using?

Answer (score 3):

In the interactive interpreter, the encoding of a string literal depends entirely on your terminal or console configuration. In your case, that is *not* set to UTF-8.

You can use the `sys.stdin.encoding` attribute to determine what codec to use:

```
>>> s = 'ö'
>>> import sys
>>> s.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
u'\xf6'
```

Alternatively, just create a `unicode` string literal (using the `u` prefix) directly; the Python interactive interpreter knows to use the `sys.stdin.encoding` codec for that case:

```
>>> s = u'ö'
>>> s
u'\xf6'
```

Comment: `locale.getpreferredencoding()` and `sys.stdin.encoding` don't necessarily return the same value.  On a US Windows console the former returns `cp1252` and the latter returns `cp437`.  In the console the latter is correct.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: ah, indeed; the win32 API `GetConsoleCP` function is used to determine the input codepage, which is not exposed in Python.